# How can I move a service to a new server but keep the same IP and port?

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

I have 2 servers in the same LAN (connected to the same switch). Each has it's own dedicated public IP address. Let's say 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2. I'm running Windows Server 2003. I have 2 game servers. Each runs on its own port, but on the same server. For example

- **Game server 1:** 1.1.1.1:1234
- **Game server 2:** 1.1.1.1:1235

I want to run Game Server 1 in the same server as it does now. I want to run Game Server 2 in the *other* server (the one with the public IP of 1.1.1.2), but I want to keep using the same IP and Port (1.1.1.1:1235).

How can I solve this without buying a router? Can I use a VPN? Is there a simpler solution other than a VPN? Will a VPN affect performance in a noticeable way (considering they are both in LAN)?

I actually don't need to use the IP 1.1.1.2 at all.

Comment: I was thinking, can the Server 1 be used as a gateway with a NAT? Does  the Server 2 need to be connected directly to Server 1 (So it would need a second NIC), or is it ok if they just share the switch. I'm new to networking so maybe this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a really tiny *nix box in front of them and configure NAT/port-redirection (masquerading). This would be performance friendly. Alternatively you could investigate a reverse proxy solution, although not all of them have the capability to deal with UDP traffic, if that is what your game servers use.

Checkout Soekris and WRAP for small *nix hardware that are efficient as network appliances. In Australia Yawarra (yawarra.com.au) retail them and their website also has good information about these boxes.

Comment: The datacenter will not allow me to add another box (without paying for rack space of course), also I receive a fair amount of traffic (about 35000 PPS and 60mbps) so I don't know if a really tiny box would work. I am extremely short on budget also. I would need some type of solution that doesn't require any extra hardware. Thanks.

Comment: Those tiny boxes are specifically designed to handle networking well. NAT or reverse proxy is what you need to implement in this case as you are differentiating ports and keeping IP addresses the same. A router wouldn't help in this case, not unless you want to do load balancing and that too will require some pretty advanced configuration. Don't give both servers the same IP while they are on the same switch fabric. You could do firewall redirection without having to put server 2 behind server 1. I don't know if it's feasible with MS Windows. You're on the right track now :)

Comment: firewall redirection? Where can I read more about that? Redirecting traffic without having to put server 2 behind server 1 would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just update clients to use new ip ? even better, give them a dns alias, so they won't have to be updated for the next change

*Anyway, for the dirty staff* :

Install the RAS feature on the first server. Choose to do nat.
Then on the nat tab, add an entry for port 1235 (choosing tcp or udp as needed), with forward to the other server's ip.

I don't know if it will works fast enough to handle 60Mb/s of traffic without lag (for games).

**On the server1, network interface usage will be twice higher** :

1. Packets for server 2 comes in (inbound),
2. It forward them to the other (outbound),
3. Server 2 will reply to server 1 (inbound),
4. Server 1 will send answer back to client (outbound)

I never tried to forward traffic to an ip on the same outside interface, so gui may block you

Comment: And how do I configure Server 2? Does it need to be behind server 1, or just connected to the same switch?

Comment: better if it's behind through another netword card (on a private lan),  even if it goes to the same switch.